# Hola como puedo ordenar mi tableview por distancia?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath) as! viewController2Cell
    let latitud = self.listaDeViviendas[indexPath.row].latitud
    let longitud = self.listaDeViviendas[indexPath.row].longitud


    let coordinate0 = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let coordinate1 = CLLocation(latitude: Double(latitud!)!, longitude: Double(longitud!)!)
    let mulitplier = pow(10.0, 1.0)
    let distanceInKm = (coordinate0.distance(from: coordinate1)) / 1000
    let distanceRounded = round(distanceInKm * mulitplier) / mulitplier
    var number = [distanceRounded]



    let sortedMalls = number.sorted { $0 < $1 }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: deberias ordenar los datos y luego utilizarlos para popular la tabla

Answer (score 0):

El proceso de ordenar por distancia lo estás haciendo bien, pero no debes de hacerlo dentro del cellforrow, date cuenta que “ordenas” cada que se instancia un renglón nuevo, haz un método , mándalo llamar en el viewdidload y cada que recibas información nueva del servidor(si lo estás haciendo online)